# Reversing (or voting/suggesting to reverse) an accepted tag synonym

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-synonyms

There needs to be a way to request/vote on undoing 'accepted' tag synonyms.

For instance: [razor](/questions/tagged/razor), Microsoft's web-only templating engine, has the synonym [razorengine](/questions/tagged/razorengine) a [NuGet package](http://nuget.org/packages/RazorEngine) and [open-source library](https://github.com/Antaris/RazorEngine) that lets you use `Razor` outside of web pages.

I have [some problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14561695) with `RazorEngine` that are specific to the library - I'm not asking anything about Microsoft's underlying `Razor` technology.

I want the tags to be specific to the NuGet package, like they are for other packages (for instance like the [Mini Profiler has its own tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mvc-mini-profiler)).

There should be a way for me to at least suggest that all questions about the `RazorEngine` are not actually about `Razor`, ideally on the [page where I can suggest new synonyms](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/razor/synonyms).

Comment: Shouldn't you just ask here for a Razor-Nuget tag?

Comment: @ChrisGerken what? For every NuGet package based on `Razor`? I don't think that would be very useful. I have enough rep to create new tags and suggest new synonyms, I just can't suggest that an existing one is incorrect or out of date.

Answer (score 2):

There is talk that at some point they will redo the synonym page and how that process will be done.  This would probably be a good item to implement then, though I think I'd require a higher voting level, and maybe even ultimately mod-approval.

For now, you basically have to get a mod interested to make it happen.